# Mechanic implications of the Psionics tag?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, spellcasting, psionics

Quite a few monsters have the *Innate Spellcasting* trait. Some of them, such as the Gith (MM) and the Neothelid (VGtM) have a trait called *Innate Spellcasting (Psionics)* instead.

I cannot recall having seen any mechanic referencing whether or not a creature is a psionic. So my question is: **Does the *Psionics* tag on *Innate Spellcasting* have mechanical implications?**

Answer (score 2):

Kind of.

- The [psionics rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Psionics) state the only effect, besides "being psionic", is that components aren't required (but I do not know of any monsters that do not say that anyway)
- There may be some effects that only trigger off "being psionic" (though I can't think of any that are relevant)
- A spell cast psionically may not be considered magical by a DM (although Sage Advice considered all spells and features that create the effects of a spell, to be magical, psionics are kind of in a slightly grey area at the moment)

Comment: I don't have the time to dig up the sources right now, but - although that was unclear in the past - I'm pretty sure that psionics are definitely considered magical in the latest rulings & publications.

Comment: Regarding the first bullet point, when a monster has innate spellcasting without psionics, only material components are not required. Verbal and somatic still are. But with psionics, no components are required.

Comment: @PixelMaster Yeah, in the errata they are considered magical. Any DM ruling to the otherwise is a ruling.

Comment: @mdrichey Correct, but since it's listed on every monster it is kind of a moot point.

Answer (score 2):

## The greater silver sword has psionic ability as attunement prerequisite

While reading a bit more about psionics, I stumbled about the magic item greater silver sword, which "requires attunement by a creature that has psionic ability" (MToF p. 89).

I also performed searches on dndbeyond with the terms "psionic" and "psionics" to see if I could find more rules specifically referencing psionics. I only found Classes and Feats (UA) granting and monsters having psionic abilities.